# Cannot locate com.android.internal.R.drawable with Appium

Tags: android, appium

I'm trying to automate the login procedure for an android app (version 4.4.2). When I leave a field (username or password) blank and click login, a red exclamation mark is printed in the blank text field and a small popup becomes visible saying that pass or user is blank.

My problem is that both elements are not visible neither in the inspector nor in the UiAutomator so I cannot check whether the element is visible. 
The programmers told me that it is a com.android.internal.R.drawable element which is printed in the text field.

Do you have any idea how I can locate the elements? Things like findElementsByxPath, ...LinkText, ...Class, and so on did not work. Also when I try to locate the element in the textfield (gettext, different size,...).

Answer (score 0):

I continued my search and as far as I can see this is currently not possible. The element is a class 'PopWindow' to which it is not possible to perform any action against: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93268
If you have any other idea/information please let me know.